# Magento - Printing order after checkout - page not found

Tags: php, magento

After I place an order using an account there is a link to print the order on the success/thanks for your order page.

The link looks like this: www.domain.com/ordersuccesspage/ordersuccesspage/print/0/id/1/1558/

I believe this is default Magento functionality. However when I click it it says page not found.

Why does it display page not found? Do I need to enable something in the configuration or is the link itself incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved by Re-indexing and by deleting cache from admin/system

And your link to print should look like this :

http://www.demo.com/magento/index.php/sales/order/print/order_id/17/